# Prevent Android Studio from Generating Data Binding Library Classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I am trying to stop Android Studio from compiling databinding XML files that I worked on and want to include at a later date when I have the time to code them.  I put a lot of time structuring the XML.  However, when I try to go back and test some of the older components in my app, it says I need to debug the XML first.

(There is not one simple fix for it, there are loads of errors that have to be coded through and pages of code that I still need to write to make these files work properly and I don't have the time to work on this section of the app yet.)

Now I have tried the "Mark as plain text" however, Android studio is still trying to build the XML out.  It uses Data Binding Library and it is still creating a set of Binding Library classes for the plain text XML files.  Do I have to rip these files out of my project or is there some way to force Android Studio to completely ignore these files?

I would like to keep them in if possible as the structure is there.

Comment: You can disable data binding in Gradle -- you had to opt into having data binding in your module's `build.gradle` file, so undo that.

Comment: @CommonsWare well I am still using data binding library in other sections of the app.

Comment: You could remove the root `<layout>` and any `<data>` elements from the affected layout files. Or, you could remove those layout files from the `res/layout/` directories (stash them somewhere else).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, this is what I had to end up doing.  The reason I was trying to avoid it was that I had written about 20 files and some of them were in multiple packages.  I suppose the lesson is add only one testable part of a section at a time and not the entire un-coded section while testing and debugging everything at once.  :/  I had created a notification list with 10 different objects that could sit in the list, each one different and going to different parts of the app.  But I didn't need this list yet so I wanted it out.

Comment: IMHO, the lesson is: do not use data binding, at least for new projects. Data binding is a dead-end technology, as Jetpack Compose will be making layout resources obsolete.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you please explain why they are or might be dead-end technologies?

Comment: @MRamzan: I did: Jetpack Compose will be making layout resources obsolete. I expect Google to be pushing Compose UI strongly over the next few years as the way that we should be writing Android apps, as opposed to using the classic `View` system and layout resources.